# Slices for Android Device (Samsung Galaxy S4-xxhpi)?

Tags: android, pixel

Samsung Galaxy S4 resolution is of **1080 x 1920**. I made a PSD of this size and did slicing.

After slicing, I put these into my project and coded something like this for ImageView.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />
```

Even when I run, it shows too big in my Android device.

I little studies over internet and found that it must divide it with 3, to get

```
1080 / 3 = 360 dp
1920 / 3 = 640 dp
```

where it says to slice it on **360 x 640.**

On the other end, I found that it must be **640 x 960**

Can anyone tell me what PSD I should choose and than do its respective slicing.

If you can give for all sizes, It would be helpful for me.

```
ldpi
mdpi
hdpi
xhdpi
xxhdpi
xxxhdpi
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### For Android Devices

LDPI- icon-36x36, splash-426x320

MDPI- icon-48x48, splash-470x320

HDPI- icon 72x72, splash- 640x480

XHDPI- icon-96x96, splash- 960x720

XXHDPI- icon- 144x144

### For Android Tablet Devices

```
LDPI:
    Portrait: 200x320px
    Landscape: 320x200px

MDPI:
    Portrait: 320x480px
    Landscape: 480x320px

HDPI:
    Portrait: 480x800px
    Landscape: 800x480px

XHDPI:
    Portrait: 720px1280px
    Landscape: 1280x720px
```

For More Details You Can see Developers Guide [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Thanks.!